# PHP DateTime - Incorrectly influenced by cookies?

Tags: php, datetime, cookies

I have written an extension to PHP's DateTime. On one of my sites, I noticed that there was really odd behavior with the dates. I deleted my cookies for that site on a whim, and the dates started behaving as they should.

Now that my cookies are gone, I have no idea how to reproduce the issue. I am concerned about giving a specific example because I don't have an actual example and I don't want to create a red herring. On place I noticed it is in my calendar application where I pass 20121116 in the URL specify the month of November, 2012 ('Ymd' format string) and it was being interpreted as a far future date, like 2098. I don't remember if it correctly interpreted the month part.

Is there a known issue/work-around? I am having clients that are reporting the issue, and I am recommending that they delete their cookies, but I would like to solve this problem without them needing to do anything. I haven't yet encountered a client technically proficient enough to send me their cookie values.

- I am using PHP Version 5.3.14
- In my .htaccess file, I set the time zone like this: `php_value date.timezone America/New_York`

---

**UPDATE**

My sites are hosted on Rackspace Cloud Sites. My current working theory is that one of the load-balanced servers has the date set incorrectly. The "X-Mapping-[random string]" cookie ties the browser to the load-balanced server with the incorrect date setting (locale?), so clearing the cookies has the potential of getting a different server.

---

**SOLUTION**

The problem was a load-balanced server with incorrect settings. Rackspace corrected it.

Comment: You will probably need to give *some* more detail than this. What exactly happens when, can you show examples of the behaviour?

Comment: Even if you can't reproduce the problem, at least describe what you mean by "really odd behaviour"

Comment: Perhaps the timezone is different?

Comment: Perhaps before asking your clients to delete the cookies, you could get them to show/tell you what the cookies look like. You could use your browser's developer tools to manually put the cookies back in place one by one on your machine, and see what the effect is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime is **not** influenced by Cookie in **any** case (that would open many security holes).
Maybe you have a custom function that analyze some cookie values and set current timezone accordingly.

Comment: I can't think of any place in my code where I change the time zone

Comment: Please refer to the solution in my OP.